# Should I create an extra user (other than root) for my web server?

Tags: ssh, debian, security, permissions, webserver

I want to host a small homepage via `node.js` from an [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com) Debian droplet. I added SSH-keys for my personal MacBook and I'm able to connect via SSH (only my MacBook is registered otherwise you are instantly kicked out and not even asked for an SSH password).

I'm currently connecting via something like: `ssh root@MY-IP-ADDRESS` on a fresh **Debian 8.6 x64** installation. This is the first time I'm setting up a *real* `node.js` server with the purpose of *actually* serving something.

Many times I read that you should definitely **not** run the server process (in this case `node`) as root. I think I'll need another user (other from root), something like *server* with just enough permission to handle the server.

I'm currently asking myself, if I even should work via **root** - should I even add a fancy `.bashrc` or `.vimrc`? Or is it preferred to spend as little time as **root** as possible?

What is the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you absolutely should. In fact in many systems you *never* log on as root ever. SSH root logins should be *disabled* and key based authentication set up.There's a lot of bad actors who attempt to brute force root and other common usernames in order to get access to anything.

As I recall the 'usual' way to do this is to have a 'proper' web server acting as a proxy - say ngnix, passing traffic to your node.js server running on a higher port.

Alternately you could set firewall to forward ports.

You certainly should avoid being root as much as possible.

What I typically do is to have one account with sudo powers, and set up one account per 'standalone' app. I store anything to do with the application in one place, and use the crontab for that account to start the application on reboot. YMMV

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any good resource/homepage where this is explained in detail? As I already mentioned: I'm already using key based authentication, but I have no idea how to setup a user/etc..

Comment: Resources is learning materials...

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, is that a problem?

Comment: @Herickson, please also note that there's a standard (i.e. "system") Debaian user named `www-data` which is specifically used to run web servers. I think it's available right away after the base system install. Run `getent passwd www-data` to verify you have this user in your system.

Comment: @Herickson - Indeed.  Questions seeking learning materials is specifically not on topic.

Comment: @Herickson so basically you should learn how to write a simple `systemd` unit file to run your `node.js` process with the credentials of that `www-data` user.

Comment: @Ramhound The question is on topic and my comment is seeking for resources to the specific answer given.

Comment: @Herickson - I disagree that your followup question is within scope, but that's what life is about, people not agreeing with you.  So I wish you luck, and encourage you, to do proper research on the subject before asking additional questions here.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, I catch it and will keep this in my mind.

Comment: @Herickson, one another point: the question is actually too broad for SO. The only thing which could be told right away to you is "use root account as little as possible". But the question of how exactly it's best to run your `node.js` application is way more open-ended. So I'd recommend asking it on the `debian-users` mailing list where it's way easier to have a discussion than on SO.